# Is it safe to fire and forget Task.add_async() on AppEngine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

The issue isn't documented
I did some basic testing before converting all Task insertions to utilize add_async, all tasks that I inserted with add_async(), but didn't wait or get_result ended up executing and I assumed it was safe

However while investigating an issue, I found an instance where the task is added async, but it didn't execute, which led me to believe that it's unsafe to fire and forget about the async task rpcs, and they should be manually wait'ed, is this the case?

Comment: Let me note that it's a great idea to set retry limits high and wait for each async operations just in case, because these things aren't well documented, or reliable, in my opinion (sometimes tasks fail without any logs - this might have caused my confusion)